# How to get rid of emoji (emoticons) in Terminal.app (OS X 10.9)

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, internationalization

I am experimenting with Twitter API.

I now have emoji characters in Terminal.app. I don't know how to handle that. How to get rid of that or use it well?

see screenshot

[image: emoji in Terminal]

Answer (score 1):

Emoji are simply unicode characters that are rendered as such by the operating system. In the following screenshot, you can see that unicode is "allowed" in filenames:

[image: Emoji in Terminal]

In fact, these are even rendered by Finder:

[image: Emoji in Finder]

To fix this, simply rename the file through Finder or Terminal.

This happens because whatever glyph substitution algorithm that they use is picking up the unicode text in the filename and replacing it with Emoji (which is a ttf font on OS X).

Comment: howto do a regular expression on those emoji? Do they work with all Open Source software from "brew"? Do they work (compatibility) on Linux and Windows?

Comment: They will not appear on Linux or Windows. I do not know if they will work with software installed through Homebrew, but they should since Terminal is rendering the text on-screen.

Comment: And if I remember correctly, Emoji fall in the unicode range U+1F600 to U+1F64F. Maybe this can help you create your regex? `text.replace(/[\u1F60-\u1F64]|[\u2702-\u27B0]|[\u1F68-\u1F6C]|[\u1F30-\u1F70]{\u2600-\u26ff]/g, "");` is what I have saved on my machine.

Comment: Original source for that regex is in an answer to the question linked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006218/replace-emoji-unicode-symbol-using-regexp-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the monochrome Unicode characters instead of the graphic emoji ones, the only way to do it is to manually remove the font called Apple Color Emoji. However, if you do this you'll lose the graphic emojis in Messages, Mail, etc. You should still get the plain monochrome character in those apps.